# Are purchasable animals overpowered?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, balance, equipment, animals, economy

I have recently discovered that you can buy a large variety of rather strong creatures for very cheap amounts. A character that is moderately specialized in handle animal can easily get a +15 by level 3. And for the price of a +1 weapon, they can instead get a [Mastodon](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/animals/elephant/elephant-mastodon/). This monster of a creature has 14 HD and can reasonably be combat trained by the character. This monster has a +20 to hit, and does a **lot** more damage than anyone at that level should be able to pull off. This problem could be made even worse if the character making the purchase has access to a spell like *animate dead*. These are much stronger than creatures at the level it would be castable, and make for cheap strong minions. (Ignoring story consequences.)

Is there something I am missing about these animals and why they are priced so low in comparison to other equipment and gear that is much less powerful?

Comment: Are you interested in answers that compare the relative value of the [various creatures for sale](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipmenT/goods-and-services/animals-animal-gear) or specifically in the Mastodon (which, based on a quick perusal might be out of the norm)?

Comment: I have noticed that this is for a large quantity of animals in general, but not all. This is not just specific to the Mastodon, but Dire animals are in a similar state as well as several dinos and a few others

Comment: "can reasonably be combat trained by the character". Are we sure about that?

Comment: As per handle animal rules, combat training is a DC 20, and that is very trivial for the character. It takes 6 weeks if the animal is untrained, or 3 if it is already trained for riding. If the party is given much downtime, or the opportunity to take downtime, this check is impossible to fail as handle animal is a skill you can take 10 on in most cases.

Comment: Infact, its even more trivial if the animal is raised, but as another commenter stated, that would require killing it. However that can be made trivial with coup de grace or some critical thinking

Comment: I have renamed your question so that its title better reflects its scope (you are asking about Mastodons, not all purchasable animals in general). I did it with an intent to ask a similar question about other purchasable animals.

Comment: I was not asking about Mastodons in specific, they were just a one of many example I used. I can name countless other animals that are powerful compared to their price.

Comment: @Erudaki Maybe this question would then benefit from including those other animals, because the Mastodon is quite notorious for being what it is, and the accepted answer boils down to "The Mastodon is big". However, there are numerous non-Huge creatures that can be used, and even some Tiny ones. E.g. regular, common bats are good for their Blindsense.

Comment: There are a plethora of animals I could include. Almost any of the "Dire" creatures. Bats like you said for a cheap detect invis. I didnt include them because I thought it would be redundant and excessive to list every possible example. I specify my question as "Is there something I am missing about these animals and why they are priced so low in comparison to other equipment and gear that is much less powerful?" A bat vs Ioun Wyrd construct is far cheaper. And I think the answers address this question well. A bat would be far harder to take around and keep than an Ioun Wyrd.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The part you're missing is

> (ignoring story consequences).

I've played with a party who were really amused about the idea that they could buy an Elephant, and then did (and named it Bongo) and brought it along on their travels. The result of them doing this was:

- losing a bunch of money on buying food and stabling
- constantly having to think about how to bring it along to the next location
- being trivially tracked by everything so inclined
- having to deal with setting up camp with something that doesn't fit in the average camp site, let alone inside a Tiny Hut
- having to run out of their Tiny hut to protect Bongo when they were ambushed at night, instead of just waiting it out
- having to leave it behind with a bunch of magical wards whenever they approached any kind of structure

In the end, they had it for probably half the campaign and I think it got into combat only once. The rest of the time, it was just a huge headache to deal with all the logistical challenges of bringing a Huge Animal into any kind of place designed for Medium Humanoids.

They really loved that elephant though, so I'm glad they bought it ;)

Comment: This is a very good answer about possible story consequences, but animal forage only costs 5 sp/day for a horse. Even if you multiply this by 15 (a real elephant can eat up to 300 pounds of grass and froots per day), it's just 7.5 gp. That's just one charge from your wand of CLW at the cost of pretty much smashing anything on your way in open grounds. Tracked or not, who cares when you have an 18 HD animal with you?

Comment: The problem is that anything other than a big city won't have 300 pounds of food per day easily available. Any place that can support an elephant (ie; cities) won't let you make any use of it and any place that lets you make use of it (ie; the open field) can't easily support it. The real price for smashing things in the field is figuring out all the logistics, which are generally non-trivial. Also being tracked is still bad, since an ambush can mean you die before the elephant wakes up.

Comment: While these are great points. Not every game is very strict on a lot of these things. The "Animate dead" spell along with a portable hole that you can stuff your pile of bones into also gets around a lot of these problems. An undead with a propper guise of life can also be far more obedient than any animal. Still at the cost of a +1 weapon.

Comment: If your game doesn't care about these things, it's going to be completely broken by allowing this. An elephant that has all the advantages of being an elephant and none of the disadvantages of being an elephant is not a balanced thing. (Also, a portable hole costs 20.000gp, so if you have one of those, the whole "it's cheap" point is lost)

Comment: I would also like to point out that, while these animals may be available for purchase *some*where, they aren't available *every*where. Good luck finding mastodons and t-rexes for sale in The Shackles or finding axe beaks and woolly mammoths in the Mwangi Expanse.

Comment: @RevenantBacon *Ultimate Equipment* raises the possibility of widespread mastodon dealerships: "The following animals [including mastodons!], mounts, and related gear can be found in most large cities. Based on its location, a settlement might not have all of these animals or related gear available at a given time (as the GM deems fit)" (80). So, yeah, one of the issues is, in fact, that every large city or bigger is—according to the game—kind of supposed to have one or more mastodons available for sale.

Comment: I love the idea of a used mastodon dealer. "This one's got all your upgrades, extended tusks, extra shaggy pelt. Only one owner, regularly fed, never taken outside the city."

Comment: @HeyICanChan "Based on its location" and "as GM deems fit" are explicit conditions to the existence of such dealerships. Were I the GM in this hypothetical scenario, the selection of available animals would be limited to creatures that were in fact native and suited to living in such an environment as the settlement is located. You aren't going to be finding *any* whales for sale in Osiria, regardless of how much you want one.

Comment: @RevenantBacon I would imagine the logistics for a whale is substantially worse than an elephant... Wikipedia says they eat about 2,000-2,500 kg (4,400-5,500 pounds) per day...

Comment: @Nelson Yeah, but the logistics of feeding it aren't a consideration if you can't even buy one in the first place.

Comment: @BaconyRevanant Sure, and that would make sense. However, the description also really does say—first, even—that the "following… can be found in **most** large cities" (emphasis mine)). If those items *can't* actually be found in *most* large cities, then the GM should make that clear. I mean, if in the campaign *most* means, effectively, *none* or *only ever environmentally appropriate animals*, that's a rules change that the players should be aware of.

Comment: @HeyICanChan You've conveniently left out the *directly following* sentence: **"Based on its location, a settlement might not have all of these animals or related gear available [...] *(as the GM deems fit)***." So I really don't think that it's a significant enough change that it needs to be announced ahead of time, since it's literally spelled out right there. So maybe don't misrepresent the rules.

Comment: This is what we call a *qualifier*, which modifies the meaning of another statement. Also, which one is first or second in a paragraph is highly irrelevant for determining which (or even *if*) one of the two is more important.

Comment: Wait what? Ambushing the elephant should be harder than ambushing the party.  It has passive perception 10 and WIS 11 to use it with; and should have greater passive perception for smell. Though I find the most glaring mistake in the stats is missing tremorsense. Real elephants have it.

Comment: @Joshua Your looking at dnd 5e elephants. Pathfinder doesnt have passive perception. That being said, an elephant has +21 perception, and a Mastodon has +24, meaning they will on average get about a 31 or 34. So still really good and still have scent. Much better than most low level party perception.

Answer (score 6):

It only has a will save of +7, and charm animal is only a LVL 1 spell, some ranger/shaman/druid with only a +3 comp, will have around 1/3 chance to gain an ally that will wreak the party

It is already a challenge when an intelligent friend is charmed, when it is just an animal, he would be very grateful to gain his freedom be killing his old master, should this one be fairly abusive, like making it goes to inhospitable zone, dark caves, getting hurt by fighting, waiting hours, or days in the same space (there is no way that a huge animal will  pass through doors...) If the master is good with the animal, it just take him out of the fight (or an opposed charisma check, against 7, to make it do something it wouldn't do).

Then, also LVL 1 there is murderous command (cleric, oracle), the closest ally will take a hit.

Dominate animal is lvl 3, way more reliable than charm animal,

You should also take a records of tricks the animal has learned it can only lean 6 tricks, and 2 will go for attack, probably one for heel, probably defend.

I will not go around with something dangerous like that.

Same problems if it was undead, another necromancer would be able to challenge the control of it, and it is a lvl 3 spell ;

So yes it is cheap, but it is also fairly dangerous, and I will not repeat the other answer, but a huge animal won't fit in many settings (can't climb, don't fly...) But it is way cheaper than any bag of holding of its carrying capacity, and you 'just' need mundane big big big bags.

Comment: I like the basis of your answer, the weak Will save. However, Charm %CREATURETYPE% does not make it your ally in combat. You could improve the answer by mentioning a different spell that also targets Will.

Comment: Charm animal only sets type to friendly, which if treated well will not cause it to also attack its allies (Assuming it is cared for well. Many creatures and animals consider good trainers family, not a captor.) . But it will prevent it from smashing the enemies. Dominate animal would be a better example, however both are made irrelephant if the animal is just raised as undead instead. Raised undead are a lot harder to challenge the control over and requires a lot more specialization

Comment: @Erudaki Raised undead might be harder to fully take control of, but any cleric or paladin with access to turn undead has a reasonable chance of sending that mastodon skeleton stampeding back towards the party.

Comment: @Erudaki I see what you did there.

Comment: if the party is level 7 and the creature has 14 HD, and is bloody (Thanks desecrate), that save is going to be a lot easier for the necromancer. Lv 5 if your one of the specialty classes that grant animate dead as a 3rd level. Clerics and paladins are good, but 3x their level in HD good? Maybe not.

Comment: I feel like undead-ing the animal is outside the scope of the question (also it has huge repercussions on the statblock that may or may not be desirable; just look at the [undead ogre](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/131605/28326) I statted out for a user a while back)

Comment: Ahh. I had intended it for it to be considered. I play a necromancer in a game and looked at these and thought it would be too op if I spent my wealth here and was wondering if I was missing something. I have an excel sheet that calculates everything out from str/dex/hd so I can quickly convert things mid combat for use.

Comment: @Erudaki In regards to raising the elephant, you do realize that you have to kill it first, which means that that 14HD combat beast will be fighting *you* before it fights anyone else as undead?

Comment: yes. However if your purchasing it i presume its not hard to shove it into a cage or bindings to make that easier, or attempt to coup de grace it while it sleeps. Its not like its an enemy when you purchase it. Killing it in the field is another story all together and while I dont think necromancers themselves are balanced, that is indeed outside the scope. So perhaps it is a fine line.

Comment: @Erudaki With regards to spending the wealth, you might also want to consider the component cost of animate dead. After all that is 350gp for every encounter behind a doorway that the beast is too big to fit through unless disassembled. Not to mention passing through towns and other places where active necromancy might be frowned upon.

Comment: Portable holes help with that as foes the spell blood money. If its a bloody skeleton and doesnt fit you can always smash it and store it for later when it can reassemble on its own. The material component cost really isnt a huge cost all things considered.

Comment: @Erudaki *Blood Money* is supposed to be a rare spell found only in a specific wizards spellbook in a specific AP, not intended for any and every wizard to just be able to learn. Most DM's ban it outright because of how broken it is. I recommend not using it.

Answer (score 1):

There are certainly creatures for sale that would make very powerful allies. The Yak (for 24gp) can trample low level enemies to death (2d6+12 damage) without even needing to roll to hit. It is reasonable for a GM to ban them for this reason.

However, it's worth noting that owning a creature does not give you full control over the creature. You will typically have to make a Handle Animal check to give it a simple instruction, which it will carry out in its own way.

Comment: Why would you need to have 13 levels to have caster level 7? If you're playing a full-caster your caster level should equal your level.

Comment: Your math is off. Lv 7 at the minimum. 2x7=14 for most casters. This can be offset further with specilization. +2x with desecrate without any spec puts that at 28hd. You can raise it as a bloody 14hd skelly at level 14 for 2k and a bit extra if you dont also use blood money spell.

Comment: Im pretty sure my specilized necro could raise it as bloody at level 5... further a high animal handling and combat training isnt hard to obtain either, and can easily hit +15 by level 1 or 2. Making the dc to give it orders unfailable, so it would be simply a matter of maintaining morale.

Comment: You seem to be confusing spell level with caster level. A level 7 full caster can only cast level 4 *spells*, but their *caster level* is 7.